# Process a combobox called from another userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a `userform` that contains a `combobox` where I can search through.

If I recall this `userform` directly, the `combobox` works fine.

If I instead start from another `userform` and press a button to open the `userform` with my `combobox`, the search won't work.

I tried with "_Change".

This is the applicable part of the first userform:

```
If InStr(I1.Text, " ") > 0 Then
    New_Pat.First.Text = Left(I1.Text, Len(I1.Text) - 1 - (Len(I1.Text) - InStr(I1.Text, " ")))
    New_Pat.Second.Text = Right(I1.Text, Len(I1.Text) - Len(Left(I1.Text, Len(I1.Text) - (Len(I1.Text) - InStr(I1.Text, " ")))))
    New_Pat.Combobox10.SetFocus
Else
    New_Pat.First.Text = I1.Text
    New_Pat.Combobox10.SetFocus
End If
New_Pat.Show
```

And this is the part of New_Pat

```
Private Sub ComboBox10_Change() 'Keydown(ByVal keycode As MSforms.ReturnInteger, ByVal shift As Integer)        'Click()      'AfterUpdate()        'Change()
    Sheets("ListOfName").Select
    ComboBox1.Value = Cells(ComboBox10.ListIndex + 2, 91)         
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the involved part of the first userform:        If InStr(I1.Text, " ") > 0 Then
            New_Pat.First.Text = Left(I1.Text, Len(I1.Text) - 1 - (Len(I1.Text) - InStr(I1.Text, " ")))
            New_Pat.Second.Text = Right(I1.Text, Len(I1.Text) - Len(Left(I1.Text, Len(I1.Text) - (Len(I1.Text) - InStr(I1.Text, " ")))))
            New_Pat.Combobox10.SetFocus
        Else
            New_Pat.First.Text = I1.Text
            New_Pat.Combobox10.SetFocus
        End If

            New_Pat.Show

Comment: Is your `_Change` code actually running?

Comment: as explained if I call the userform directly the combobox works well, while it does NOT work if I go from the first one