# Combobox...second test

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a userform that contains a Combobox where I can search through. If I recall this userform directly, the combobox works fine. If I instead start from another userform, I press a button and open the userform with my combobox, this it does not work properly, as the search won't work. I tried with "_Change" and also other solutions ... any ideas to try?

This is the involved part of the first userform:

```
        If InStr(I1.Text, " ") > 0 Then
            New_Pat.First.Text = Left(I1.Text, Len(I1.Text) - 1 - (Len(I1.Text) - InStr(I1.Text, " ")))
            New_Pat.Second.Text = Right(I1.Text, Len(I1.Text) - Len(Left(I1.Text, Len(I1.Text) - (Len(I1.Text) - InStr(I1.Text, " ")))))
            New_Pat.Combobox10.SetFocus
        Else
            New_Pat.First.Text = I1.Text
            New_Pat.Combobox10.SetFocus
        End If

            New_Pat.Show
```

And this is the code of the involved combobox of New_Pat

```
Private Sub ComboBox10_Change() 'Keydown(ByVal keycode As MSforms.ReturnInteger, ByVal shift As Integer)        'Click()      'AfterUpdate()        'Change()
    Sheets("ListOfName").Select
    ComboBox1.Value = Cells(ComboBox10.ListIndex + 2, 91)         
End Sub
```

P.S. Combobox1 is a second Combobox I need for other searches...

Comment: how's its different from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582575/vba-still-problems-with-comboboxes

Comment: The previous one had been flagged as closed :-)

Comment: It got re-opened :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process a combobox called from another userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582575/process-a-combobox-called-from-another-userform)

Comment: Nope...at the moment I have found this solution. if instead of "New_Pat.Show" I put "Exit sub" and then launch "New_Pat.Show" from a button it works well. But that's not what I want. It is definitely an initialization problem: what can I try?